# Fast ArgumentNullException with attributes. It is possible?

Tags: c#, attributes, methods

Is there any fast way to verify null arguments
via attributes or something?

Convert this:

```
public void Method(type arg1,type arg2,type arg3)
{
     if (arg1== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg1");
     if (arg2== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg2");
     if (arg3== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg3");
     //Business Logic
}
```

Into something like this:

```
[VerifyNullArgument("arg1","arg2","arg3")]
public void Method(type arg1,type arg2,type arg3)
{
      //Business Logic
}
```

Ideas? thanks guys.

Comment: Sorta related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980689/c-code-contracts-vs-normal-parameter-validation

Comment: Your approach breaks refactoring. What happens when you renamed arg1 to something else?

Comment: The same, as comments, thay change.

Comment: What about an argument-level attribute like `Method([NotNull] type arg1, [NotNull] type arg2, [NotNull] type arg3)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236408.aspx) built into .NET 4.  That's probably as close as you'll get.  There's quite a bit more information at [DevLabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx) if you chose to go this route.

Comment: Code contracts don't really solve the OP's problem at all, as it still requires just as much typing. But I prefer them because of the potential compile-time checking that can be done.

Comment: @Josh Einstein: You're right, in this case it's not much less code.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Answer (score -1):

not an attribute, but similar idea:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static void VerifyNullArgument(params object objects)
    {
        if (objects == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("objects");
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < objects.Lenght; index++)
        {
            if (objects[index] == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Element is null at index " + index,
                    "objects");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in your example method

```
public void Method(type arg1,type arg2,type arg3)
{
    SomeClass.VerifyNullArgument(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    //Business Logic
}
```

Comment: This will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  You need to take a `Expression<Func<object>>[]`.

Comment: `if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(obj.ToString());`  This will end up throwing a NullReferenceException when it tries to call obj.ToString();

Comment: haha... silly mistake. :) I obviously wasn't thinking when I wrote that bit. :) But the basic idea is there.

Comment: -1. Fix your "silly mistake" before someone copies and pastes it.

Comment: It's not just a silly mistake.  In order to actually work correctly, this needs to be much more complicated.

Comment: Slaks is right. Look at the improvements I made at Joel's code to get it right.

Comment: @Steven: And it's still wrong.  You should throw an `ArgumentNullException` containing the _name_ of the argument that was null.  Also, remember that one of the arguments in the middle might be allowed to be null.

Comment: @SLaks: You are completely right. This idea just isn't going to work. I rather stick with CuttingEdge.Conditions ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. The code contracts are definitely a better solution.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, tha code analisys is still teasing the "verify your params - warning"